# Is the issue in my java code or the SMTP server? 452 4.5.3 Too many recipients error while sending mail through SMTP using java

Tags: java, email, smtp, jakarta-mail

I am sending a mail to multiple users via a SMTP server using the below java method. When the number of users is below 200, all the mails are delivered. But  when the number of recipients is more than 200, I get a **com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPAddressFailedException: 452 4.5.3 Too many recipients** and none of the mails get delivered.

I guessed this might be due to configuration in the SMTP server and informed the admin. But he says the SMTP server is configured to send mails to upto 500 recipients at a time and the issue is in my program. But I don't see any property where I set the max recipients for SMTP.
Am I missing something or can I just relax and keep blaming the server admin?

```
public void sendAllMails(List<String> mailIds,String subject,String text) 
{
    String smtpHost="127.0.0.1";
    String fromAddress = "user1@mymail.com";
    String mailUser = "user1";
    String password = "pass1";
    String mailId=null;
    try{
        java.util.Properties properties = System.getProperties();
        Session session = Session.getInstance(properties, null);
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(fromAddress));

        Iterator<String> iterator=mailIds.iterator();
        while(iterator.hasNext()){
            mailId=iterator.next();
            message.addRecipients(Message.RecipientType.BCC, mailId);
        }

        message.setSubject(subject);
        message.setContent(text, "text/html");
        session.setDebug(true);

        Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
        transport.connect(smtpHost, mailUser, password);
        transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
        transport.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's the **server** complaining about the number of recipients. But you should fix it in your **code** to send only to resonable number of recipients (and if more send multiple times to part of the recipients only)

Why? It's SMTP. So that first server will pass on the mail to the next SMTP       along the line - and you have no control over each server in that line.

Note that Transport has a method to specify recipients in code - which you already use -  and if you recycle Transport instance and your Message you can keep the headers intact - showing all your > 200 recipients - or rather not as you're adding BCC only.